# UnknownTimeZoneError in Pandas.Timestamp.now

Tags: python, pandas, timezone, django-timezone

I want to append the Timestamp of current time for my timezone, but don't know where to find the correct value of my timezone. Apparently, it's Islamabad/Karachi, but no success.

Here is my small code chunk

```
import pandas as pd
...
#df -> a dataframe
df.to_csv('C:/path/to/file-'+str(pd.Timestamp.now())+'.tsv', mode='a', index=None, sep='\t', header=False)
```

Desired output file name is

`file-10;17;52--29-06-2020`    for `file-hour;minutes;sec--day-month-year`

I know `:` is not allowed in names

Comment: if you are in your tz, them datetime.now() should give it; If not then use the UTC timeshift wrt you zone to create the correct time;

Comment: In my case timeshift is +5 hours. Can you please put an answer to make my code working?

Comment: I have a sample below; I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for datetime module. I was going to kill a fly with Atomic Bomb(pandas timestamp) :p

Comment: use `datetime.now().strftime('%H;%M;%S--%d-%m-%Y')`

Comment: Ok Thanks! if you have time, please add an answer as well

Comment: that's fine, I've basically just added strftime to @Aditya 's answer. find more format codes here: https://strftime.org/

Comment: the interesting thing here to me is actually *why* `pd.Timestamp.now()` throws `UnknownTimeZoneError` - what do you get if you call `datetime.now().astimezone()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF you are in the required TimeZone, then simply doing the below will work;

```py
from datetime import datetime
time_now = datetime.now() # Will give your local time
```

OR,

We can get the same by shifting the UTC time by let's say by `5 hours`

```py
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta
now_utc = datetime.utcnow() # Current time in UTC
my_tz_time = now_utc + timedelta(hours=5) # now we can shift the time by 5 hours easily
```

EDIT -1

Based on the link shared by @MrFuppes, in the second approach, we should do the below,

```py
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta
now_utc = datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc) # Time in UTC
my_tz_time = now_utc + timedelta(hours=5) # now we can shift the time by 5 hours easily
```

Comment: save yourself some trouble and [avoid datetime.utcnow](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2019/11/utcnow.html) :)

Comment: I have updated with the same for future visitors; Thanks @MrFuppes